# Should we use "whether" or "if" in indirect speech?

Tags: conjunctions, reported-speech

Ex:

1. My brother asked me **if** I wanted a pizza or a sandwich.
2. My brother asked me **whether** I wanted a pizza or a sandwhich.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Whether" Vs "If"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68256/whether-vs-if)

Comment: @Chenmunka I was reading the duplicate and am curious. Is it ELL's view that the following sentence is acceptable? "I was unsure of **if** it would rain or snow." compared with "I was unsure of **whether** it would rain or snow."

Comment: @Rathony To my ear they are both acceptable in colloquial use and unacceptable in formal use. In formal use I'd delete both *of*s.

Comment: @StoneyB I think the answer in the duplicate seems to be wrong about it especially when **of** is replaced with **about**. I am not sure whether I should leave a comment to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Ranthony Your first sentence is incorrect and should be: He was unsure **if** it would rain or snow *(no of)*.  Your second sentence using **of whether** is correct.

Comment: @Rathony Neither of those answers is very good.

Comment: @StoneyB In that case I will leave it up to high-rep users and moderators. I didn't closevote this question because I felt the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences talk about the same thing: your brother's query about a **choice** between pizza or a sandwich.

Both are commonly used.

You may also note that if only **one alternative** was mentioned, **whether** will still need a contrast:

> My brother asked me **if** I wanted pizza
>   My brother asked me **whether** I wanted pizza **or not**